# Zerodimensional, compact space is homeomorphic to spectrum of some ring -- elementary attempt

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology

Let $X$ be a zerodimensional (X has a base with clopen sets) and compact (quasicompact and Haussdorf) topological space and I would like to prove that $X\cong Spec(A)$ of some ring $A.$ I don't want to refer to Stone duality because I didn't had this theorem on a lecture. I try to show that $X\cong Spec(C(X,\mathbb{Z_2})),$ where latter means continuous functions with values in $\mathbb{Z_2}.$ It is related with question:

[Spectrum of a ring homeomorphic to a compact, totally disconnected space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2024993/spectrum-of-a-ring-homeomorphic-to-a-compact-totally-disconnected-space)

Obviously, I can show injectivity of map given in the answer of this question, continuity, also that image of open base set is open base set. I have a trouble to deal with the surjectivity (attempt which works for real-valued functions doesn't work here because of addition in $\mathbb{Z}_2.$ I'm stuck in this point and I would like ask you for a help. It is possible that ring on a right isn't correct. I underline that I don't want to use the Stone duality, I prefer an elementar way.

Comment: Do you really mean $X\cong C(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$? Shouldn't you have $X\cong \text{Spec}(C(X,\mathbb{Z}_2))$?

Comment: It's a typo, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Henno Brandsma has given lots of good hints, but let me spell things out a bit more for you.

Let $R = C(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$. For any $x\in X$, let $\mathfrak{p}_x = \{f\in R\mid f(x) = 0\}$. It is easy to check that this is a prime ideal in $R$. This gives a map $\varphi\colon X\to \text{Spec}(R)$, $x\mapsto \mathfrak{p}_x$. And this map is continuous, since a basic open set in $\text{Spec}(R)$ is given by $D_f = \{\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec}(R)\mid f\notin \mathfrak{p}\}$ for $f\in R$, and $$\varphi^{-1}(D_f) = \{x\in X\mid \mathfrak{p}_x\in D_f\} = \{x\in X\mid f\notin \mathfrak{p}_x\} = \{x\in X\mid f(x) \neq 0\} = f^{-1}(\{1\}),$$ which is open in $X$, since $f$ is continuous and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is discrete.

Now it suffices to check that $\varphi$ has a continuous inverse $\psi\colon \text{Spec}(R)\to X$. For each $f\in R$, let $Z(f) = \{x\in X\mid f(x) = 0\}$. Let $\mathfrak{p}\in \text{Spec}(R)$, and let $Y = \bigcap_{f\in \mathfrak{p}} Z(f)$.

*Claim:* $Y$ is nonempty.

Since $X$ is compact, and each set $Z(f)$ is closed, it suffices to show that the family $\mathcal{Z} = \{Z(f)\mid f\in \mathfrak{p}\}$ has the finite intersection property. Let $f,g\in \mathfrak{p}$. Then $Z(f)\cap Z(g) = Z(f+g+fg)$, and $f+g+fg\in \mathfrak{p}$, so $\mathcal{Z}$ is actually closed under finite intersections. Suppose for contradiction that $\emptyset\in \mathcal{Z}$, witnessed by $Z(f) = \emptyset$ with $f\in \mathfrak{p}$. Then $f$ is the constant function $1$, contradicting our assumption that $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime. We have shown that $\mathcal{Z}$ is closed under finite intersections and does not contain $\emptyset$, so by compactness its intersection $Y$ is nonempty.

*Claim:* $Y$ is a singleton.

Suppose for contradiction that $x,y\in Y$ with $x\neq y$. Since $X$ is zero dimensional and Hausdorff, there is some clopen set $C\subseteq X$ with $x\in C$ and $y\notin C$. Let $f$ be the function which sends all points in $C$ to $0$ and all points not in $C$ to $1$ ($f$ is continuous since $C$ is clopen). Then $f(1-f) = 0\in \mathfrak{p}$, and $\mathfrak{p}$ is prime, so either $f\in \mathfrak{p}$ or $(1-f)\in \mathfrak{p}$. In the first case, $y\notin Z(f)$ contradicting $y\in Y$, and in the second case, $x\notin Z(1-f)$, contradicting $x\in Y$.

We have shown that $Y = \{x\}$ is a singleton, and we can define $\psi(\mathfrak{p}) = x$.

It remains to check that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are inverses and $\psi$ is continuous. I'll leave that to you.

Comment: A bit more... :) Thanks! I had the problems only with that Y is nonempty, another claims was known by me. Thanks once again!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer was helpful for you, you can always upvote and accept.

Answer (score 4):

Try to show that a prime ideal in $R=C(X,\Bbb Z_2)$ corresponds to a unique point in $X$ using compactness. (The sets $\{f^{-1}[\{0\}]: f \in I\}$ form a zero-set filter, when $I$ is an ideal in $R$ etc.)

Then show $\textrm{Spec}(R) \simeq X$ via this correspondence.

Comment: I tried on this way: for real-valued functions I can get a sum of squares of finitely many functions, which comes from compactness. But on $\mathbb{Z}_2$ 1+1=0 and this attempt doesn't worki. I don't have a idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: @jpatrick why not take $\Bbb R$ as the codomain for the ring of functions?

Comment: Because X has a clopen basis and it seems for me that if reals are in a codomain then the ring of real-valued continuous functions isn't zerodimensional (not every prime ideal is maximal.)

Comment: @jpatrick for sure not all prime ideals are maximal in that case. I'm not sure of it holds in the $\{0,1\}$ case either BTW.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It follows from the fact that every element of $C(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is an idempotent (i.e. $C(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a Boolean ring) that every prime ideal is maximal in this ring.

Comment: $C(X,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ is a boolean ring (each element is idempotent) and it is easy to show that prime is maximal because quotient by prime is a domain with elements as idempotents, so quotients are fields.

Comment: @jpatrick So what's your problem with my proof sketch to get an element of $X$ from a maximal/prime ideal? Just that you cannot show FIP?

Comment: I don't know how to prove that for a maximal ideal zero set is not empty on case of $\mathbb{Z}_2.$

Comment: @jpatrick $Z(f) \cap Z(g)=Z(1+(1+f)(1+g))$, right?, over $\Bbb Z_2$, of course.

Comment: This equality is correct, but how one can use it to show that exists a point which is a zero for all $f$ in maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}?$ Maybe I'm just so tired but I don't see how this identity is used; particularly zero set on the right could be empty...

Comment: @jpatrick we get an ultrafillter and this has a unique limit.